# Python - Creating Nested JSON File from a CSV File

Tags: python, json, nested

I'm new to Python and need help in creating a nested JSON file in a specific format. I searched numerous articles but none could solve it.

I have the following CSV file:

```
application,memberOf
    TestApp02,"CN=g.cmbu_symphony_aws_sre,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,OU=Common,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM"
    TestApp02,"CN=g.cmbu_symphony_aws_vrops,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM"
    TestApp03,"CN=g.aws_sre,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,OU=Common,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM"
    TestApp03,"CN=g.cmbu_symphony_aws_vrops,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,OU=Common,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM"
    TestApp04,"CN=g.cmbu_symphony_aws_sre,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM"
```

The JSON output file should like this:

```
{
        "TestApp02": [{
                    "memberOf": ["CN=g.aws_sre,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,OU=Common,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM",
                     "CN=g.cmbu_symphony_aws_ops,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,OU=Common,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM"
                        ]
            }],
        "TestApp03": [{
                    "memberOf": ["CN=g.aws_sre,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,OU=Common,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM",
                     "CN=g.cmbu_symphony_aws_ops,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,OU=Common,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM"
                        ]
            }],
        "TestApp04": [{
                    "memberOf": ["CN=g.cmbu_symphony_aws_sre,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM"]
            }]
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

This is the code I have:

```
import pandas as pd 
import json
  
df = pd.read_csv("csve.csv")

print(df)


j = df.set_index(['application','memberOf']) \
      .groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[-1], axis=1) \
      .agg(lambda x: x.values.tolist()) \
      .reset_index() \
      .to_json(orient='records')

print(json.dumps(json.loads(j), indent=2))
```

But it doesn't produce the following output:

```
{
    "TestApp02": [{
                "memberOf": ["CN=g.aws_sre,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,OU=Common,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM",
                 "CN=g.cmbu_symphony_aws_ops,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,OU=Common,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM"
                    ]
        }],
    "TestApp03": [{
                "memberOf": ["CN=g.aws_sre,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,OU=Common,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM",
                 "CN=g.cmbu_symphony_aws_ops,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,OU=Common,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM"
                    ]
        }],
    "TestApp04": [{
                "memberOf": ["CN=g.cmbu_symphony_aws_sre,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM"]
        }]
}
```

Comment: Why is the inner structure a list of dictionaries with one member instead of just a dictionary? And if the dictionaries all have the same key, why not simplify to a list value where the key is implied?

Comment: You won't find articles that solve your *exact* problem - which is *not* how to convert CSV to JSON. You're trying to convert data from one shape to a completely different one. It looks like you need to *group* rows before you export the data. If you used pandas, you could read the CSV with `read_csv`, group by `application` with `groupby` then write the result as JSON with `to_json`

Answer (score 0):

to get the output you want:

m.py

```
import csv
import json

data = {}
with open('m.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        app = row["application"]
        memberOf = row["memberOf"]
        if app not in data:
            data[app] = [{"memberOf": []}]
        data[app][0]["memberOf"].append(memberOf)
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

cat m.csv

```
application,memberOf
TestApp02_Sriram,"CN=g.cmbu_symphony_aws_sre,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,OU=Common,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM"
TestApp02_Sriram,"CN=g.cmbu_symphony_aws_vrops,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM"
TestApp03,"CN=g.aws_sre,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,OU=Common,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM"
TestApp03,"CN=g.cmbu_symphony_aws_vrops,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,OU=Common,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM"
TestApp04,"CN=g.cmbu_symphony_aws_sre,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM"
```

output:

```
# python3 m.py
{
    "TestApp02_Sriram": [
        {
            "memberOf": [
                "CN=g.cmbu_symphony_aws_sre,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,OU=Common,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM",
                "CN=g.cmbu_symphony_aws_vrops,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "TestApp03": [
        {
            "memberOf": [
                "CN=g.aws_sre,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,OU=Common,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM",
                "CN=g.cmbu_symphony_aws_vrops,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,OU=Common,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "TestApp04": [
        {
            "memberOf": [
                "CN=g.cmbu_symphony_aws_sre,OU=Generic,OU=Groups,OU=Corp,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bhakta Raghavan! That's exactly what I was looking for. Awesome!